# How to suppress Spring configuration INFO messages?

Tags: java, spring, maven, logback, slf4j

I've recently started using Spring via the STS IDE. I've been trying to get rid of all the INFO log messages when running a standalone application. I've looked at similar questions here and in other places, which have helped me to reduce the number of INFO messages but not suppress them completely

I've now created a minimal Spring/Maven legacy application (*i.e.* not using Spring Boot) test application:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationContext.class))
        {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

with an empty application context:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationContext
{
}
```

I've cut the POM down to the minimum:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestLog</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

According to the STS POM editor, that results in the following list of resolved dependencies:

- aopalliance
- commons-logging
- logback-classic (runtime)
- logback-core (runtime)
- slf4j-api
- spring-aop
- spring-beans
- spring-context
- spring-core
- spring-expression

Following the answers listed here to similar questions, I've included the following `commons-logging.properties` file:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog=ERROR
```

and the following `logback.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

   <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>

  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

With the logging configuration files in place, running the Java application produces the following output:

```
[INFO] AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7e6cbb7a: startup date [Wed Dec 06 13:00:17 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[INFO] DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@649d209a: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,applicationContext,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Hello
[INFO] AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7e6cbb7a: startup date [Wed Dec 06 13:00:17 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[INFO] DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@649d209a: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,applicationContext,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Where are the [INFO] lines coming from and how do I suppress them?

Comment: I believe they are coming due to the root logger, try logging.level.root=WARN . At it worked for me. I am using Spring boot

Comment: Where do I put that?